# KeyTypedEvent KeyEvent's KeyCode is always 0?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

I have a Java Swing application in the NetBeans IDE.

I made a form and attached a KeyListener to my various controls as such:

```
    jButton1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            keyTypedEvent(evt);
        }
    });
```

and `keyTypedEvent` is defined as such:

```
private void keyTypedEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
{                               
System.out.println(evt);
appendDisplay(String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar()));
}
```

I added a `println` to the `evt` to see what happens and to verify that my keylistener does work.
When I build and run my application, I realized that the output always seems to have a `keycode = 0`

To verify this, I had changed my println to be `evt.getKeyCode()` and it is always returning 0.

I could be completely misinterpreting what KeyCode does, but I thought that it would coorespond with the values in Oracle's documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE

For instance, VK_ESCAPE has a value of 27.

Comment: Don't use KeyListener. Either use DocumentListener or Swing Key bindings.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `keyTyped()` event is only used for keys that produce character input. If you want to know when any key is pressed or released, you need to implement `keyPressed()` or `keyReleased()`.

From the [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) API:

> "Key typed" events are higher-level and generally do not depend on the
>   platform or keyboard layout. They are generated when a Unicode
>   character is entered, and are the preferred way to find out about
>   character input....
>
> For key pressed and key released events, the getKeyCode method returns
>   the event's keyCode. For key typed events, the getKeyCode method
>   always returns VK_UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 3):

- all suggestion about `KeyListener` for `JButton` are wrong, meaning `Button1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {`
- [these events are implemented and correctly in `JButtons API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), use [`SwingAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) or add [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for listening `Mouse and Key Event` from/to `JButton`
- basically everything is described in Oracle tutorial about [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Answer (score 0):

It very depends on key that has been pressed. Probably you need `KeyListener` with `keyPressed` method override, because `keyTyped` not triggered on non-printable characters.

Look at the difference between `keyTyped` and `keyPressed` here:
[KeyListener, keyPressed versus keyTyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped)