# KeyTyped Events Will Not Register

Tags: keylistener, keyevent, keyboard-input

I am learning how to code keyboard input with a keylistener. I got it working with the following program:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class KeyboardInput extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    public KeyboardInput(String s) {
        super(s);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label);
        add(panel);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
        KeyEvent e = event;

        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
        case java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_A:  System.out.println("A");
        case java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_D:  System.out.println("D");
        case java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S:  System.out.println("S");
        case java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_W:  System.out.println("W");
        case java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: System.out.println("Space");

        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_0) {
            System.out.println("0");
        }

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            System.out.println("W");
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // nothing yet

    }

}


public class Core {

public static boolean isRunning = true;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    new KeyboardInput("Keyboard Input Testing");

}
}
```

Unfortunately, there is one big problem: while the keyPressed events are working, the keyTyped ones aren't. Is this an error in my code, or could this be due to a faulty keyboard?

An additional side clarification question that I have is why is the KeyboardInput initialized in the main class initialized without being declared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyTypedEvent KeyEvent's KeyCode is always 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714888/keytypedevent-keyevents-keycode-is-always-0)

Comment: ricky3350 I used the W key, which should have a keyTyped event.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#KEY_TYPED) for key typed events:

> This event is generated when a character is entered.

To determine the input from the event, you therefore need to use the `getKeyChar()` method as opposed to the `getKeyCode()` method, which will always be `VK_UNDEFINED`.