# KeyEvent in java does not work for alphabets or numerics but works fine for control, alt,up and down.but was not working for alphabets or numbers

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

i scanned the internet and couldnot find solution
so, i was trying to integrate keypad shortcuts but later realised that the keyevent does not work
properly which i could not find the reason for it works for others. but not for me .

here is the code:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {

    NotePad note;
    public KeyHandler(NotePad note){
        this.note=note;
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("some key is pressed");
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                System.out.println("s is down");
                note.file.save();
            }
            else if (e.isControlDown()&&e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_O)
                note.file.open();
            else if (e.isControlDown()&&e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z)
                note.functionEdit.undo();
            else if (e.isControlDown()&&e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Y)
                note.functionEdit.redo();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

in the key typed method i first used it with control down it happens but not with other keys which are alpahbetical or numeric.

i was trying to implement the keypad shortcuts basically fire keypad input like ctrl+s and all and get them to perform certain function . but it does not work.

here is my implementation of keyListener.

```
public void createTextArea(){
        textArea=new JTextArea();
        textArea.addKeyListener(keyHandler);
        textArea.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(
                new UndoableEditListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
                        um.addEdit(e.getEdit());
                    }
                }
        );
        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        frame.add(scrollPane);
```

//            frame.add(textArea);
}

Comment: and how do you use this Handler? To which component did you add them? how did you add them?

Comment: i just added the key listener to text area in here is some code for reference.
public void createTextArea(){
            textArea=new JTextArea();
            textArea.addKeyListener(keyHandler);}

Comment: it was a snippet

Comment: don't put "snippets", put examples that are sufficient to reproduce the issue. So, don't add code in comments, it 's not clear. Also, since we have no idea whether or not that method is called, it's pretty pointless.

Comment: Key listeners are essentially deprecated. Instead, use key bindings

Comment: edited the question.  I don't understand the problem that is happening with me . without understanding that problem i would not like to transition to key bindings.

Comment: you said you edited the question. You didn't. And why would you not migrate to Key Bindings? Sticking to something that doesn't work anyway isn't necessarily the better choice.

Comment: now its done sorry for the previous in convenience for some reason the edited content was not displayed previously.
I just want to understand the problem before shifting just the why of it?? you understand.

Comment: again: we don't even know whether that method is even called, so most we can do is guess.

Comment: yeah it is called while i was debugging it.

Comment: let me give you a link to github repo: https://github.com/vedangpandey/TextEditor

Comment: I would recommend key bindings as a starting point

Comment: `keyTyped` is, generally, a bad choice - the `keyCode` is always `0`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714888/keytypedevent-keyevents-keycode-is-always-0 for some details.  Use `keyPressed` or `keyReleased`, but better yet, use the key bindings API

Comment: @VedangPandey don't just post a link to your github, put a minimal reproducible example in your question

Comment: it was just a keyEvent on textArea @stultuske there was nothing more than it . all you had to do was take a main class and then run a jframe with this on top of it. this does seem like a minimal code other than that to me. but  still i appreciate the advice and would look  into it in future.

Comment: An even easier approach than key bindings is to add a JMenuBar to your application, and assign [accelerators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke)) to its JMenuItems.  Much like Windows Notepad used to do, before it was ribbonized.

Comment: ohh would check it out for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you're better off making use of the [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/misc/keybinding.html) API.  This helps you decouple the functionality as well as control the level of focus under which the events are triggered.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.event.UndoableEditEvent;
import javax.swing.event.UndoableEditListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.undo.UndoManager;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new NotePad());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class NotePad extends JPanel {

        private UndoManager undoManager;

        public NotePad() {
            undoManager = new UndoManager();
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 10);
            Document doc = textArea.getDocument();
            doc.addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() {
                @Override
                public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
                    undoManager.addEdit(e.getEdit());

                }
            });
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(scrollPane);

            InputMap inputMap = textArea.getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
            ActionMap actionMap = textArea.getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "Save");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "Open");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "Undo");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Y, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "Redo");

            actionMap.put("Save", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Save");
                }
            });
            actionMap.put("Open", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Open");
                }
            });
            actionMap.put("Undo", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (undoManager.canUndo()) {
                        System.out.println("Undo");
                        undoManager.undo();
                    }
                }
            });
            actionMap.put("Redo", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (undoManager.canRedo()) {
                        System.out.println("Redo");
                        undoManager.redo();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        protected void save() {
            System.out.println("Save");
        }

        protected void open() {
            System.out.println("Open");
        }

        protected void undo() {
            System.out.println("Undo");
        }

        protected void redo() {
            System.out.println("Redo");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have been a mad help buddy. but could you tell me why the keylistener would not work for me . my guess is the laptop keyboard maybe. because the api is too old or something could you explain?? if you can please do . even if not, Thank you for telling me what  to do. I am grateful.

Comment: @VedangPandey As I said in my comments, `KeyTyped` is a bad choice for what you're doing, it seems to be used to generate the textual result of the combination of `keyPressed/Released` (I'm assuming), you'd be better of using `keyPressed` or `keyReleased`, however, the key bindings are still a better choice, as they provide a much higher level of decouple and configuration (ie, it might be nice to be able to save/open a documentation when the text area isn't in focus)