# Java KeyListener: Is the "Backspace" key pressed in KeyTyped

Tags: java, keylistener, backspace

How do I tell if the user pressed the "Backspace" key from inside of the KeyTyped method? They value from `arg0.getKeyChar()` is not `KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED`, and `arg0.getKeyCode()` is `KeyEvent.VK_UNDEFINED` as it always will be inside of the KeyTyped method. Do I have to use the KeyReleased/KeyPressed methods and flag a boolean? Which method fires first? KeyReleased or KeyTyped?

Comment: keyPressed is fired when the key is pressed (down)
keyReleased is fired when the key is released (up)
keyTyped is fired just after the user types a Unicode character into the listened-to component.

Comment: @Flot2011 So is KeyReleased before KeyTyped? Or does it depend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like KeyTyped cannot detect keys that don't have a visual representation. I assume this includes backspace.

[KeyListener, keyPressed versus keyTyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped)

Comment: What does it give in the getKeyChar() then?

Comment: Just found it. When I cast arg0.getKeyChar() to an int, I get the number 8. Would that be the same on other computers? (for the Enter key, I get 10, for ESC, I get 27. Are these values standardized?)

Comment: I believe that backspace does have a proper unicode encoding, so getKeyChar() is going to report that

Comment: So backspace has a unicode character, which is what getKeyChar() is reporting, but it's not "printable" so getKeyCode() gives you the undefined.

Comment: Yeah, but If you cast getKeyChar() to an int, it will always give the number 8. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it should always give you the number 8 because that's the unicode encoding :) No problem! Was fun researching.