# KeyPressed and KeyTyped Confusion

Tags: java, awt, keypress, keylistener

I have searched about difference between `KeyPressed`and `KeyTyped` Events but still I'm not clear about that . One thing I have found is Keypressed is triggered first than KeyTyped .
Please clarify me when these are triggered exactly . Which is appropriate to use for which purpose ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this using Swing or AWT components?  For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`keyPressed` is fired whenever any key press occurs. `keyTyped` is fired when a key is pressed that can be converted into a unicode character. If the shift key is down, for example, pressing "a" will tell `keyTyped` that you typed a capital A, and `keyPressed` will just get the "a" key, without capital or lowercase designations. You cannot call `event.getKeyChar()` from `keyPressed`, because there is no key char associated with the events. Characters only come from `keyTyped`.

The basic idea is that `keyTyped` is used to find characters that are typed, and `keyPressed` is used for obtain raw key presses.

Answer (score -1):

`KeyPressed` happens when the key goes down.  `KeyTyped` happens when the key goes down and then back up.  I'm not sure if "in rapid succession" is a requirement, and if it is, how fast "rapid" is.

Edit: `KeyTyped` is actually when a unicode char is sent from the keyboard.  USUALLY, the key behavior is that it goes down and then back up in rapid succession.

Taken from: [KeyListener, keyPressed versus keyTyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped)