# How to use KeyEvent in JavaFX project?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I have searched for a long time for how to write a `KeyEvent` to allow my Button clicks by `ENTER key`. Note that I'm using JavaFX and `FXML` files.

The problem is that when set in the onKeyTyped text field in the FXML file, the FXML Files doesn't accept it. It says `Handle method not found`. It just accept `ActionEvent` method so I have tried this code:

```
 @FXML
 private void key (KeyEvent evt) throws IOException{ 
       if (evt.getCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
       String az = text1.getText();
       //c.1
       if(az.contains("1")){ 
          String hh = text11.getText();
          Socket socket = null;
          InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress (hh,80);  
       } 
    }
}
```

So please can anybody help me?

Comment: I would be very suprised (and disappointed) if this was the default behaviour of buttons in JavaFX.  I think you need to have a look through [Handling JavaFX Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm) and [Using JavaFX UI Controls](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm). I'd be very suprised if something like `button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {` didn't deal with both the key event and mouse event, just like Swing does...

Comment: <palm-dock-with-face> Okay, so apparently [Enter] isn't the default key...Try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758782/fire-buttons-onaction-with-enter-in-javafx) instead

Answer (score 10):

You have few issues with your code :

1. You are using `onKeyTyped` instead of `onKeyPressed`. For more information [visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797231/keypressed-and-keytyped-confusion)
2. You are most probably using [`java.awt.event.KeyEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html), which will not work with `JavaFX events`. Try to use [`javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html).

   The reason I came to this conclusion is because JavaFX doesn't support [`KeyEvent.VK_ENTER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_ENTER) but instead have [`KeyCode.ENTER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html#ENTER)

A concrete example is shown below, you can use the same to convert it into FXML:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        Button button = new Button("Press Me!");
        pane.setCenter(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        button.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Pressed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```