# Miles to Kilometers converter (event driven)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I need to create a `JPanel` that displays **Miles** and **Kilometers**. When you input numbers into one, it converts it to the other using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

I cannot figure out how to correctly get the `KeyListener` to execute the conversion. I'm not looking for an answer just some guidance or a link to an example similar to it.
Thanks.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Ch09Asg extends JFrame {
    private JTextField jtfMiles = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField jtfKilo = new JTextField(10);

    public Ch09Asg() {
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));        
        p1.setSize(400,250);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Mile"));
        p1.add(jtfMiles);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Kilometers"));
        p1.add(jtfKilo);
        jtfMiles.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        jtfKilo.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jtfMiles.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(){
        });

        jtfKilo.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(){
        });
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //double mi = convertKmtoMi 
            //Double.parseDouble(jtfMiles.getText());
            //double kilom =
            //Double.parseDouble(jtfKilo.getText());
            //---------------------------------------KILOTOMILE

            String kmStr = jtfKilo.getText();      //Note 3
            double km = Double.parseDouble(kmStr);

            //... Convert it
            double mi = convertKmToMi(km);                //Note 4

            //... Convert it to a string and set mi textfield
            jtfMiles.setText("" + mi); 

            //--------------------------------------MILESTOKILO
            String miStr = jtfMiles.getText();      //Note 3
            double mi2 = Double.parseDouble(miStr);

            //... Convert it
            double km2 = convertKmToMi(mi2);                //Note 4

            //... Convert it to a string and set mi textfield
            jtfMiles.setText("" + km2); 
        }
    }

    public static double convertKmToMi(double kilometers) {
        // Assume there are 0.621 miles in a kilometer.
        double miles = kilometers * 0.621;
        return miles;
    }

    public static double convertMitoKm(double miles) {
        // Assume there are 0.621 miles in a kilometer.
        double kilometers = miles / 0.621;
        return kilometers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ch09Asg frame = new Ch09Asg();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("Mile/Kilometer Converter");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, `if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);` does nothing, and `System.out.println("43");` sbould be `System.out.println("42");` :-)

Comment: I'm unsure of how to link the KeyEvent to the ButtonListener class.  I was using the System.out to see if it at least read an Enter in the text field.  I'm completely lost.  Sorry if my code is all over the place.

Comment: @user2616657, read the answers given. You should NOT be using a KeyEvent. You simply add the ButtonListener to the text field using the addActionListener() method.

Comment: Thanks so much! I got the keys to work and compute but for the text fields to work I have to only have one in the actionPerformed area.  Do I create another actionPerformed for the other text field calculation?

Comment: See also [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding `KeyListeners` to the text fields, which doesn't actually work that well, you are supposed to add `ActionListener`s, in the same way you woul dadd action listeners to a button. They are activated when you press enter.

Comment: +1 for the actionListener, try to advice for using [**Key Bindings**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead `KeyListener` or `ActionListener`.

Comment: +1, for taking advantage of the API. @Azad, the text field was designed to use an ActionListener. There is no need to create your own key bindings for the Enter key. The key bindings for the Enter key will invoke the ActionListener.

Comment: so something like jtfMiles.addActionListener(new ActionListener())

Comment: @camickr: Thanks for correcting me. I must change my comment to *instead of KeyListener*.

Answer (score 2):

Instead using KeyListener you can use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

`KeyListener` is not proper for what you are doing cause when you use keyListener get executed every key is (typed, released or pressed).

So **if you use KeyBinding you bind the action to an specific key**

```
AbstractAction enterAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //conversion code here example

    }};
 String key = "ENTER";
 KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);
 component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(keyStroke, key);
 component.getActionMap().put(key, escapeAction);
```

**And the best you don't have to have focus or be focusable**. You can use these JComponent constants

```
WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT 
WHEN_FOCUSED 
WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
```

Comment: generally good advice to use key bindings but not in this case. A JTextField already has a key binding for the Enter key. It will invoke the ActionListener.

Answer (score -1):

from: jcpartri

Hello!

this link might help you. It also lies within stackoverflow.com.
Is there any reason you switch to a KeyListener for one and an ActionListener for another?
The link below suggests you use keyReleased method instead.

[KeyListener, keyPressed versus keyTyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped)

Comment: I was trying to see which one would work.  I will check out the link thanks.