# How to input a specific number of words in java?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to input an array of strings in java according to the following specification:

*Input:A text containing K English words (where K <= 5000), with spaces and punctuation marks*

My approach is to use an array of strings, each string containing a word and taking input using `java.util.Scanner.next()` inside a loop.

My problem is how to stop taking inputs when the user hits enter. Any idea?

Comment: Why are you asking user to enter 5000 words, rather than asking from him a file containing those words?

Comment: @Rohit for some reason, lets just say I have to take input from the console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped

Comment: Does not `Scanner` finish command-line input if you hit Enter anyway?

Comment: Use scanner.nextLine(), and it will contain the text entered by the user, containing all the words and punctuation marks. Then parse this text if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Scanner`. Read the lines that the user enters. If the user enters an empty line then exit the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        final String read = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("".equals(read)) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(read);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use two Scanner objects to handle this like so:

```
Scanner inScan = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = sinScan.nextLine();
while (line.length() > 0) {
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
    while(lineScan.hasNext()) {
        String word = lineScan.next();
        // process this word.
    }
    line = inScan.nextLine();
}
// loop should exit when the user enters a blank line.
```