# JavaFX: KeyTyped event on ComboBox not firing

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, eventhandler

Our company recently received the source code for a JavaFX application which we will be developing further. I am currently setting up the development environment and i have encountered a problem that Google can't solve.

The application contains an autocompleting combobox, which filters the available values when the user enters a search string.  The code is as follows:

```
        final ComboBox<Sifrant> inputCB = new ComboBox<Sifrant>();
        inputCB.setId(formName + "_" + field);
        inputCB.setEditable(true);
        inputCB.setPrefWidth(nextControlDoubleSize ? 500 : 300);

        inputCB.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                //etc. etc.
```

I know that this code is correct, because it works correctly on our customer's demo system.

But when i run the application, the handle method is never executed. But it does work if i replace the keyTyped event with a keyReleased event.

My question is, which factors could possibly affect this behaviour?

Changing the code is out of the question, since it works properly for our customers anyway. Besides, from what i have read, using the keyTyped event is supposed to be preferred to using keyReleased, since it handles key combinations better.

I'm running the project with NetBeans 8.0 and Java 1.7.0_45.
The company which previously developed the application used NetBeans 7.2.1 and Java 1.7.0_6.

Comment: Well read the answer in this question it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped

Comment: The `KEY_TYPED` event is probably _consumed_ by the nested `TextField`. That doesn't explain, however, why it works in production. Maybe the implementation of `TextField` switched from using `KEY_PRESSED` to `KEY_TYPED` between the versions?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this question has a pretty obvious answer. It all started working properly when i switched to JDK 1.7.0_6.

But i guess it's useful that this thread exists in case somebody else gets stuck on a similar problem.

Since nothing is obviously wrong with the code, this probably means that it is a bug which was introduced into Java between versions 1.7.0_6 and 1.7.0_45.

Comment: If it works with `1.7.0_6`, it should work with `1.7.0_45`, unless you have written some inside `handle`, which is not supported any longer :)