# keyDown() vs keyTyped()

Tags: java, input, keyboard

When using a java class implementing "KeyListener", what is the difference between the "keyDown()" and "keyPressed()" methods? When would it be advantageous to use one or the other? Examples of usage would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [KeyListener, keyPressed versus keyTyped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped)

Comment: Because you're saying keyDown and keyPressed, but also mention keyTyped, I'm not exactly sure which listeners you're asking for.

Comment: Direct duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diff between keyDown and keyPressed is

`keyDown: jQuery / Javascript`
`keyPressed: Java`

It is advantageous to use the one that's appropriate for the language you are programming in.

KeyListeners have fallen out of style anyway. Instead, you should consider using Key Bindings.