# change the contents of a JFrame by clicking keys

Tags: java

How would I change the contents of a JFrame by dynamically clicking keys, in this example I want to change the contents through two JPanels I have created, when i click up I want to change to Panel2, and when I click down I want to change to Panel3, but I want the JFrames contents only to change (I want to stay in the same JFrame) there is no errors with the code, I am just a bit confused on how to solve this issue.

```
class Drawing extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

int num = 1;
public Drawing() {
            Panel2 jPanel2 = new Panel2();
            Panel3 jPanel3 = new Panel3();
            if(num == 1){
               add(jPanel2);
               remove(jPanel3);
               pack();
            }
            if(num == 2){
               add(jPanel3);
               remove(jPanel2);
               pack();
            }

           // be nice to testers..
           setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           setVisible(true);
           addKeyListener(this);
}
```

and then i have the keypressed method to change num to either 1 or 2 depending on what key is pressed (i also implemented keyReleased and keyTyped but I didn't include them to add space)

```
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP){
                num = 1;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN){
                num = 2;
            }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {

            new Drawing();

    }
```

and here is the two panels that change the graphics of the page

```
class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    Panel2() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("BLAH", 20, 20);
        g.drawRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
        repaint();
    }
}
class Panel3 extends JPanel {

        Panel3() {
            // set a preferred size for the custom panel.
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString("BURP", 20, 20);
            g.drawRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
            repaint();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in your use case, don't use keyTyped event because it is only triggered

> when the unicode character represented by this key is sent by the
>   keyboard to system input

. There is no system input in your UI. Checkout this for more details: [KeyListener, keyPressed versus keyTyped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071757/keylistener-keypressed-versus-keytyped)

Instead, use **keyPressed** or **keyReleased** event.

Secondly, you need explicitly invoke `add(jPanel2);remove(jPanel3);` when you are handling the event. Set `num = 1` doesn't do anything.

Thirdly, you need to call `jPanel2.repaint();` after `add(jPanel2);remove(jPanel3);` to make sure the panel paint the content you want.

Fourthly, **always call** `super.paint(g);` to initialize the painting canvas correctly!

So, to put them all together, you have:

```
public class Drawing extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

int num = 1;
Panel2 jPanel2 = new Panel2();
Panel3 jPanel3 = new Panel3();

public Drawing() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setSize(300, 300);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

private void changePanel() {
    if (num == 1) {
        remove(jPanel3);
        add(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.repaint();
        pack();
    }
    if (num == 2) {
        remove(jPanel2);
        add(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.repaint();
        pack();
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_UP) {
        num = 1;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_DOWN) {
        num = 2;
    }
    changePanel(); // do the actual swap of the panels
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Drawing();
}
}

class Panel2 extends JPanel {

Panel2() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); //always call!
    g.drawString("BLAH", 20, 20);
    g.drawRect(200, 200, 200, 200);
}
}

class Panel3 extends JPanel {

Panel3() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); //always call!
    g.drawString("BURP", 20, 20);
    g.drawOval(200, 200, 200, 200);
}
}
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much, I am a bit new to java and I truly appreciate the help! I just have one question, why do we need to call super.paint(g) if we already initialized it by just calling paint(Graphics g)?

Comment: @connor glad it helped